# Manually assign value to a hibernate UUID

Tags: database, hibernate, spring, uuid

As we know, in hibernate, configure the generator of a id to "uuid" , then hibernate will auto generate a UUID value to the id field when saving a new object.If configuring the generator to "assigned", the id must be assigned a value before saving a object.

And I found that if configuring the generator to uuid and assigning the id a value manually, the hibernate will change the value to a new UUID one.

My question is, when the generator is configured as uuid, how to manually assign a value to it?

PS: I use spring HibernateDaoSupport to save.

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.save(Ojbect obj)
```

Thanks!

Comment: system AA creates,saves and sends messages, and receive reply message. In the process the id of a message is used as key flag.  Now, there are messages from system BB want to add into AA , and receive reply message from AA. In order to do least changes on system AA, i need to use the id from system BB as the id of messages in system AA.

Answer (score 13):

If you need it only in rare special cases, the simpliest way is to issue `INSERT` queries in native SQL instead of using `save()`.

Alternatively, you can customize generator to achieve the desired behaviour:

```
public class FallbackUUIDHexGenerator extends UUIDHexGenerator {
    private String entityName;

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, Dialect d)
            throws MappingException {
        entityName = params.getProperty(ENTITY_NAME);
        super.configure(type, params, d);
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
            throws HibernateException {            
        Serializable id = session
            .getEntityPersister(entityName, object)
            .getIdentifier(object, session);       

        if (id == null)
            return super.generate(session, object);
        else
            return id;
    }
}
```

and configure Hibernate to use it by setting its fully qualified name as `strategy`.